# Rebuild JSON format

Tags: php, json, csv

I have JSON like this:

```
{
    live: {
        "name": "Nik",
        "age": "22",
        "car": "car1",
        "price": "1800"
    },
    live: {
        "name": "Nik",
        "age": "22",
        "car": "car2",
        "price": "2500"
    }
    live: {
        "name": "Nik",
        "age": "22",
        "car": "car3",
        "price": "1980"
    }
}
```

And need to convert it to this:

```
{
    live: {
        "Nik": {
            "22": {
                "car1": {
                    "price": "1800"
                    },
                "car3": {
                    "price": "2500"
                    },
                "car2": {
                    "price": "1980"
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to translate each point to distinguish as an array. 
In order that you could create like (php):

```
echo somevar["live"]["Nik"]["22"]["car2"];
```

and this return "2500"
How i can make that?

Also i have dirt csv:

```
live,Nik,22,car1,1800
live,Nik,22,car2,2500
live,Nik,22,car3,1980
```

Comment: What language are you using ?

Comment: Improve format of your PHP code `echo somevar["live"]["Nik"]["22"]["car2"];`

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: That is not JSON. Use a validator: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Input and output data structures are not equal. In input, parent node for "age" is "live", whilst in output is not defined or "22". First restructure input data into desired output, then you can easily reformat into JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Your input is not syntactically or semantically valid JSON.  You have an object with three attributes that have the same name ("live").  Furthermore, JSON attribute names are required to be quoted strings.

I would expect any legitimate JSON parser to reject this.

---

My recommendation would be to redesign your input format to make it valid JSON.  That is much simpler than writing a custom parser for this vaguely JSON-like format.